# Font Awesome + SmartSlider Showing on Firefox and Chrome but not Safari

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On https://f860ffcc56.nxcli.net/. I have a smart slider piece at the very top of the website with a simple animated Font Awesome downward chevron. On pretty much every browser (FireFox, Chrome, Arc, Brave, Edge, Opera, etc...) it is showing as expected. On Safari however it is not showing up. As far as i can tell it is not a z-index issue but i really am stumped on this one as to why it isn't working. I've tried changing the way Font Awesome is being loaded with no avail.

Comment: what  says your browser inspector, did you check https://caniuse.com/ ?

Comment: Only `woff2` is available in your custom FontAwesome Font face, You need `.ttf` file as well for Safari, iOs, android, etc.

Comment: @VijayHardaha This is being loaded from a CDN via FontAwesome directly.

Comment: I will suggest you contact the plugin author/developers and let them know about this issue and wait for a solution in the next plugin release. and In meanwhile if you have to solve the issue on your then you need to modify the font face code file and also generate different type of font file using available `woff2` file.